# Simple exercise in cohomology

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology

I know this is a simple exercise but I am stuck unfortunately.

Question:
Use de Rham cohomology to prove that the sphere $S^2$ is not diffeomorphic to the torus $T$. You may assume that $H^1(\mathbb{R}^2) = \{0\}$.

Answer: For the sphere $S^2$, one can show that $H^1(S^2) \cong \{0\}$, for the torus one can show that $H^1(T) \cong  \mathbb{R}^2$. Now I don't know how to proceed, what I vaguely understand is that different cohomology implies the manifolds cannot be diffeomorphic. How can I make this precise ? In particular, I must be missing something because I don't know how to make use of the given fact $H^1(\mathbb{R^2}) \cong \{0\}$.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: If $f: M \longrightarrow N$ is a diffeomorphism, then the induced map $f^\ast: H^\ast(M) \longrightarrow H^\ast(N)$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: a) $H^1(T)$ should be $\mathbb{R}^2$. But that perhaps doesn't matter in your question.
b) In Henry's Comment the induced map, which indeed is an isomorphism, maps $H^*(N)$ to $H^*(M)$.
c) If you really already know $H^1$ of $S^2$ and $T$, then there indeed is no need to use $H^1(\mathbb{R}^2)=0$, but do you?

Comment: @BenA. oops, yes that's supposed to say $H^1(T) \cong \mathbb{R}^2$, thanks for pointing that out I corrected it accordingly! Concerning your last question I was able to look up these results. However I'd love to argue "from scratch" using only the hint - what are the key steps that I'd need to take ? Thanks very much!

Comment: Well, you will have to compute some cohomology groups I guess. The only way involving $H^1(\mathbb{R}^2)=0$ I see is: If the torus and the sphere were isomorphic then by stereographic projection, $\mathbb{R}^2$ would be isomorphic to the torus minus a point. Then it's left to show that $H^1(T\setminus\text{pt})$ isn't trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The de Rham cohomology is *functorial* in the sense that if you have a smooth map $f: M\to N$ between two manifolds then you have an induced map on the $p$-th cohomology groups
$$ f^*: H^p(M) \to H^p(N)$$
given by the *pullback*, which is defined on every 1-form $\omega$ by the following formula

$$f^*\omega(X(p)) = \omega(f_*(X(p)))$$

**Lemma.** Let $M$ and $N$ smooth manifolds and $f: M\to N$ a smooth map then the pullback map $f^*$ sends closed forms on $N$ to closed forms on $M$ and exact forms on $N$ to exact forms on $M$.

The rest is proving the following (easy) properties of the pullback

(1). $(f\circ g)^* = g^* \circ f^* $
 (2). $Id^* = Id $

Now you only have to see that if $f: M\to N$ is a diffeomorphism then $f^*: H^p(M) \to H^p(N)$ is an isomorphism for every $p$. So if $S^1$ and $T$ where isomorphic their $1$-th cohomology groups would also be isomorphic.

**Note**. You can give another proof using the hint by proving that the cohomology of the torus minus a point is the same as the *figure eight* cohomology, i.e. $H^1(S^1\vee S^1)\cong \mathbb{R}^2$.